# Solution with over 100 projects takes over five minutes to build

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, project-management, prism

I have a solution with over 100 projects. It takes a long time to build, and sometimes Visual Studio crashes during the build.  How can I deal with this issue and minimize the pain?  Have we gone horribly, horribly wrong somewhere?

Some background on the problem:

We are using CAB with WPF, and each module has a ui assembly and a "server" assembly, which is really just a layer for the database.  There is only one team, with about 5 developers.

I don't know how many classes or how many lines of code.

Comment: Why dont you use its command line alternatives?

Comment: How many classes per project? How many lines of code total? How many developers/teams? How often is each of the projects changing (can some be pre-built)?

Comment: What is wrong with taking 5 minutes to rebuild 100 projects? Building shouldn't take as long as Rebuilding.

Comment: Though this doesn't directly address your problem, something to think about is replacing your HDD with a SSD.  I went from rebuilding in 46 seconds to rebuilding in 7 seconds with all other hardware remaining the same (OCZ Summit 120GB) - it was money well spent.

Comment: my company's app has over 100 projects, well over a million LOC.  A rebuild takes 30-45 minutes even on high end workstations.  You don't have a problem yet :P  (we do; we're fixing it by moving to a new compiler and new hardware... tests indicate build times of less than 10 minutes).

Comment: rmeador-- I would love more details on your problem.  Can you add it to the list of answers?

Comment: Is there a tool to determine lines of code and number of classes?

Comment: NDepend can calculate code metrics pretty well.

Comment: "Is there a tool to determine lines of code and number of classes?" - To find the number of classes, do a find-in-files (Ctrl-Shift-F) for the word "class" (case-sensitive, whole-word only) - there'll be false-positive on a generic's "where T : class", and on comments which contains the word "class", but I think it should give the right order of magnitude; alternatively, just count the number of *.cs files and assume one class per file. To count lines of code, I do a find-in-files for "`;|\}`" (regular expressions enabled) to count lines which contain ';' or '}'.

Comment: Lol @ ChrisW's poor man's static code analysis.  Nice!

Comment: FWIW, by that measure I have a solution which has 40 projects, 400 classes, and 40000 LOC: and it takes 15 seconds to rebuild, on a not-especially-powerful laptop. They're all C# projects though, no CAB files.

Comment: ChrisW... it's talking about Composite Application Block files, not Cabinet files ;-).  They are assemblies, but most of them probably have resources and UI code that take a lot longer to compile.  If he's built it wrong and there are a lot of interdependencies among modules that could cause the project build time to balloon as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is a bit short on specifics, but I imagine the crashing is just a workstation resource issue more than anything.  100 projects isn't a problem in itself as long as there are good reasons for having that many, but by the time you get to over 10 projects, I would hope that you have some sort of management structure in place for them.

Do you really need to be building all 100 projects, all the time?  You can switch off individual projects for building using the configuration manager, and you can create solution files with a subset of the total number of projects.

For example, we have 36 projects for one of the enterprise apps I work with.  Along with that, we have multiple solution files and configurations designed to allow our devs to load only the projects and configuration that they need in order to work with given subcomponents of the application.  In other words, they're only ever loading some subset of the 36 projects.  Our build server takes care of putting everything together.

I suggest doing some analysis on your application and finding out what you can consolidate, and what you can partition into other solution files.

Comment: And dependency evaluations take longer the more projects you have in a solution - this one place where having multiple solutions or configurations can help.  Turn down the message logging to report only errors-console writes slow things down somewhat.

Comment: Can you elaborate on dependency evaluations?

Comment: what if someone changes a signature of a shared component?  It won't cause a build fail in your solution because you don't have all of the projects loaded at the time.

Comment: VS evaluates the dependency chain (Project A uses Project B which uses Project C...) to decide in what order to build the Projects in a Solution.  The more Projects there are, or the more involved their dependencies, the longer it takes to figure that out.  It's a one-time upfront cost on each run.  If you have tuned Solutions that only include the things they *need*, you're not doing unnecessary tail-chasing or compiling unused modules.  We have a separate Solution for what we consider our "class library" that gets built once in a blue moon.

Comment: Yeah, changing a signature can be a breaking change if you don't rebuild everything.  It's part of the trade-off between speed and simplicity.

Comment: Re: the above: this is one reason Continuous Integration is useful.  Would have saved me a "bummer" email during our build last night...

Answer (score 3):

Your question seems to have more to do with the design of your solution and less about the ability of VS to handle 100 projects.  You really want to know if the fact that your solution takes a long time is a code smell for "holy crap we have designed this wrong".

**If you have a 1:1 relationship between "UI" assemblies and "Server" assemblies, they are logically the same and *could* be combined.**

It's ok for CAB/CAG module assemblies to have all of their dependencies in one assembly in my opinion.  If you intend on sharing data access code across several modules, then it would make sense to break it out into a separate assembly.

**If you decide this approach isn't appropriate**, what we usually do is **have several smaller solutions** that allow us to test a few related modules together locally during development, but have **one large solution that our build servers build** out.  This way, long build times are experienced by a dedicated build machine, rather than our local dev boxes (this is a good approach for even the smallest of projects, as well).

Comment: I think you are right-- I think I am asking a code smell question. I didn't even realize this till now.

Comment: I can tell you one other thing.  If your Modules are not autonomous (that is, if you can't delete them and have your shell and all other Modules still load) then they aren't properly designed Modules.  Modules should be as independent as possible.  There are times when ModuleDependencies are appropriate, but they should be few and far between.

Answer (score 2):

Do they all need to build at the same time?  If not, you can go into the [Configuration Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx) and only select the ones you need built at the present time.

Although it seems to me that 100 projects in a solution is quite a bit.  Is this really necessary?  Can you break it up into smaller related solutions, or are there really this many projects that are inter-dependent on each other?

Comment: The problem is that developers may change signatures when they shouldn't.  Projects not loaded into their customized solution will then fail to build. I assume this could be handled with continuous integration, but we haven't gone this far yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on an individual project in the Solution Explorer and select the option to build just that project. If there are any necessary projects in the build order, it will build those too, but this allows you to only build the necessary items.

Answer (score 0):

The default solution configurations Debug and Release always checks all projects, and builds the ones that are not up to date. You can create your own solution configuration where you disable the build option for projects that you know doesn't need checking.